# Animated Sidebar breaks on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to build an animated sidebar that slides in and out when you click the button. This was quite easy to achieve however I ran in to a problem when making the sidebar 'more' responsive. Basically, I wanted the sidebar to be 200px wide when the width is less than 500 and 300px wide otherwise. This was done in a media query. The problem I've run into is that when you resize the window the sidebar goes out of position if you have already run the function before resizing.

This problem can occur for example if a user rotates their mobile screen whilst using the sidebar and so I feel it's best to try and fix it.

Here is the jQuery:

```
function sidebar(){
    var menuWidth = $('#menu').width();
    if($('#menu-link').hasClass('hidden')){
            $('#menu-link').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.push').animate({right: "-=" + menuWidth});
        }else{
            $('#menu-link').addClass('hidden');
            $('.push').animate({right: "+=" + menuWidth});
        }

};

$('body').on('click', '#menu-link', sidebar);
```

The sidebar changes to 200px <500 and is otherwise 300px. What is the best way to code this or is it better to keep it simple by just always making the sidebar 200px even though it's not as aesthetically pleasing at larger resolutions.

Here is a link to a JSFiddle of my code
https://jsfiddle.net/fqcydqu7/

Edit: Sorry, to explain the actual problem clearly - Before you resize, this code runs fine and is perfect. However, if you run this code (ie. open and close the sidebar) and then resize the window so the media query is active you will see that the sidebar is out of position by 100px. The opposite will happen if you reverse the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys I came up with a solution for my problem.

Basically, I remove the media query from CSS and set the div to always be 300px.
The jquery uses a variable that is updated whenever the window is resized to judge how much to slide the menu. (200px or 300px).

here is the code:

```
// variable is set to 0 by default
var menuWidth = 0;
//call to function that will set this variable
setWidth();
function setWidth(){
    if(windowSize <= 800){ //if its less than 800px wide, set the variable to 200px (the menu is still 300px)
        menuWidth = "200px";
    }else{
        menuWidth = "300px"; //otherwise set the variable to 300px
    }
}
$(window).resize(function(){ //when a user resizes the window, run the setWidth function to readjust the variable
    setWidth(); //this re-runs setWidth

    //the following closes the menu if it's already open to avoid glitches
    if($('#menu-link').hasClass('hidden')){
    $('#menu-link').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.push').animate({right: "-=" + menuWidth});
}
});


 //nav slide
function sidebar(){
   if($('#menu-link').hasClass('showing')){ //checks to see if the nav is showing or not
            $('#menu-link').removeClass('showing'); //remove the showing tag
            $('.push').animate({right: "-=" + menuWidth}); //closes the nav
        }else{ //if the nav doesnt have showing tag it must be hidden
            $('#menu-link').addClass('showing'); //add the showing tag
            $('.push').animate({right: "+=" + menuWidth}); //open the nav
        }

};
```

With this code, the menu will only slide out by 200px when the window is less than 800px wide and 300px if it's wider. The div will always be in the correct position even if the user rotates the mobile or changes the window width.